# Localhost on Mac causing system-wide problems?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, localhost, terminal.app, node.js

I had some trouble with my 2013 MBP bogging down this summer (apple wasn't sure why...too many chrome tabs or filesystem corruption. in any event a complete reinstall fixed it). I've been doing web development with no trouble (other than the aforementioned issue) on the machine for more than a year. until....

Last week when I fired up node on a local server, my whole machine slowed down - extreme visual lags and unresponsiveness to the point that I had to force quit terminal and chrome. Node eventually crashes as well, showing this output:

`exception in nodemon killing node`

Upon restarting terminal I get these messages:

`Last login: Thu Sep 25 10:03:32 on ttys001
-bash: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
-bash-3.2$`

This persists until I restart my whole machine. I haven't been working much over the last two weeks to try and give the computer a break, but every time I try to start up my typical dev workspace (sublime text, maybe 10 chrome tabs open, one instance of nodemon/node running), starting node causes the same problems. I really have no clue what's going on and it's concerning me. Hopefully this is the right forum...any help appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like node is forking too many subprocesses, and using up the system's process limit. Try running the Activity Monitor utility (*before* starting nodemon/node), choose View > All Processes, then start node and see if the process list explodes.

Comment: You're right, it is generating dozens of subprocesses. How do I stop this from happening/ any ideas why it would start happening seemingly randomly? I'm running the latest stable node release, and the problem persists when I just use node and not nodemon.

Comment: I don't know much about node, but my guess would be that it's something in the application or your configuration that's causing it, not node itself.